# Plotly animated scattergeo graph animation map plot

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-python

I am trying to build a simple animated scattergeo plot using the python plotly package.

I have a numpy array containing latlon coordinates for 30 locations in china. I want to make a simple animation where each marker increases in size when I press play.

```
frames = []

for i in range(24):
    frames.append(
        go.Frame(
            data=[
                go.Scattergeo(
                    lon=stnUsed[:, 1],
                    lat=stnUsed[:, 2],
                    marker=dict(
                        color='red',
                        size=10*i,
                    ),
                    mode="markers",
                )
            ]
        )
    )

scattergeo = go.Scattergeo(mode="markers")

fig = go.Figure(data=[scattergeo], frames=frames)

fig.update_layout(
    geo=dict(
        projection=dict(type="orthographic"),
        showland=True,
        landcolor="white",
        countrycolor="black",
        showcountries=True,
        lataxis=dict(
            range=[18, 53],  # adjust the latitude range to cover China
            showgrid=True,
        ),
        lonaxis=dict(
            range=[73, 135],  # adjust the longitude range to cover China
            showgrid=True,
        ),
    ),
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            type="buttons",
            showactive=True,
            buttons=[
                dict(
                    label="Play",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[
                        None,
                        dict(
                            frame=dict(duration=200, redraw=False),
                            fromcurrent=True,
                            mode="immediate",
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
                dict(
                    label="Pause",
                    method="animate",
                    args=[
                        [None],
                        dict(
                            mode="immediate",
                            transition=dict(duration=0),
                            frame=dict(duration=0, redraw=False),
                        ),
                    ],
                ),
            ],
        )
    ],
)


fig.show()
```

This code creates a blank world map in my browser, there are no markers visible but hovering over the locations of where they should be displays the popup text. Pressing play or pause does nothing. However, when I double click the plot; all the markers appear and are huge. So double clicking jumps to the end of the animation. How can I make the animation work?

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks a lot.

edit: my data looks like this np.array(

['DSHZ' '121.879648337197' '30.9486139558595' '27.5126043949276']

['FEXI' '121.523220432506' '30.8331346945489' '28.9024866688996']

['GXAA' '107.689668334226' '23.1698405155104' '89.9570063613355']

['GXCO' '107.373940391047' '22.3695432229922' '124.829504701308'])

Comment: where is numpy array which containing latlong coordinates. Please attach data with question to debug output.

Comment: I have added in the data

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by changing the redraw variable inside updatemenus to True